# Sql sum of count field with different product name once

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is there any good method to get the count of different product once. 
for example

```
/* the table like */
id      count         product
 1       5              a
 2       2              b
 3       6              c
 4       2              a
 ......
```

I want to get the sum of product use one sql command. because the product number is very large.

the value like

```
a b c
7 2 6
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select product, sum(count)
from table_name
group by product
```

You might want to go through tutorial of group_by clause
http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php

Comment: 3Q, this resolv my problem

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple `sum` and `group by`

```
select product, sum(count)
from mytable
group by product
```

Comment: I guess he would need to use sum function on count column.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that straight after hitting the button to post it... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if you looking for pivote result as you done in your question , if yes use this

```
SELECT Sum(CASE 
             WHEN ( product = 'a' ) THEN ` count ` 
           ELSE 0 
           END)AS a, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN ( product = 'b' ) THEN ` count ` 
           ELSE 0 
           END)AS b, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN ( product = 'c' ) THEN ` count ` 
           ELSE 0 
           END)AS c 
FROM   table1
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd9b7/1)

result:

```
 A  B  C
 7  2  6
```

note this query is only if you have 3 limited values on product.